# The arrow helper popup on a custom control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Im createn a custom control (user control) and I now want to add that arrow that appears on most of controls that displays a popup to fill some properties that are important for the correct usage of the control.

This is what I want to implement

[image]

That arrow on the right top corner of the control.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: See [.NET Windows Forms custom designer doesn't refresh the menu](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7905255/719186)

Comment: That helps me a lot! thanks! Now I want to insert a verb as an input where you can insert some text. But the verb I think works only as a link to an action.